# Why is curl (launched by homebrew) looking in .nix-profile?

Tags: macos, curl, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

A while back I had nix installed but I have removed it, however now when I try to install threadscope I get the follwowing error:

```
Henriks-MBP:trial henke$ brew install homebrew/gui/Threadscope
==> Installing threadscope from homebrew/gui
==> Installing dependencies for homebrew/gui/threadscope: libpng, freetype, fontconfig, pixman, gettext, libffi, glib, cairo, ghc, jpeg, libtiff, gobject-introspection, gdk-p
==> Installing homebrew/gui/threadscope dependency: libpng
    ==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/libpng-1.6.21.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz

    curl: (77) SSL: can't load CA certificate file /Users/henke/.nix-profile/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
    Error: Failed to download resource "libpng"
    Download failed: https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/libpng-1.6.21.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
    Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
    ==> Downloading ftp://ftp.simplesystems.org/pub/libpng/png/src/libpng16/libpng-1.6.21.tar.xz

    curl: (19) Given file does not exist
    Trying a mirror...
    ==> Downloading https://dl.bintray.com/homebrew/mirror/libpng-1.6.21.tar.xz

    curl: (77) SSL: can't load CA certificate file /Users/henke/.nix-profile/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
    Error: Failed to download resource "libpng"
    Download failed: https://dl.bintray.com/homebrew/mirror/libpng-1.6.21.tar.xz
```

Now why is homebrew trying to find things in `.nix-profile` and what can I do to install threadscopes dependencies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't homebrew specifically looking into the `.nix-profile` directory. This is a fragment of having `nix` installed.

When you installed `nix`, it installed its own CA certs. Check the value of `SSL_CERT_FILE`. in my case:

```
$ echo $SSL_CERT_FILE
/Users/my-user/.nix-profile/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

I have have had issues with this cert when attempting to use `curl` with `https`, which is what homebrew is doing.

I'm assuming you just recently removed `nix` and still have that variable set in your shell. If you just close any currently open shells and open brand new ones, this should be fixed.

You could also try `unset SSL_CERT_FILE` in any open shells instead of closing / opening them all.